# Problem: I want to execute a code, but part of it is in another folder

Tags: c++

The code below is 21Templates.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Stack.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    Stack<string> p(100);

    p.push("python");
    p.push("haskell");
    p.push("C++");

    //p.desempilhar();
    if(p.isEmpty())
        cout << "Pilha vazia!\n";
    else
        cout << "Pilha NAO vazia!\n";
    if(!p.isEmpty())
        cout << "Topo: " << p.peek() << endl;
    else
        cout << "A pilha esta vazia!!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

And the code below is Stack.h:

```
#ifndef __STACK_H_
#define __STACK_H_
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
    Declarando a criação de um template para classe Stack.
    Stack aqui é um template, não uma classe propriamente dita.
    Ao ser declarada da maneira correta se torna uma classe de fato.
*/
template <class T>
class Stack {
    private:
        int top;
        T* a;
        int MAX;

    public:
        Stack(int MAX);
        bool push(T x); //Adiciona um T a stack.
        bool pop(); //Remove o T mais acima da stack.
        int peek(); //Retorna o T mais acima da stack.
        bool isEmpty(); 
};

//Declarando uso de um template. template <class T>
template <class T>
//"Stack<T>" é uma classe baseada no "template <class T>".
Stack<T>::Stack(int MAX){
    a = new T(MAX);
    top = -1;
    this->MAX = MAX;
}

//Declarando uso de um template. template <class T>
template <class T>
//"Stack<T>" é uma classe baseada no "template <class T>".
bool Stack<T>::push(T x) {
    if (top >= (MAX - 1)) { 
        cout << "Stack Overflow" << endl;
        return false; 
    } else { 
        a[++top] = x; 
        cout << x << " pushed into stack" << endl; 
        return true; 
    } 
} 

//Declarando uso de um template.
template <class T>
//"Stack<T>" é uma classe baseada no "template <class T>".
bool Stack<T>::pop() {
    if (top < 0) { 
        cout << "Stack Underflow" << endl; 
        return false; 
    } 
    else {
        cout << a[top--] << " Popped from stack" << endl;
        return true;
    } 
} 

//Declarando uso de um template.
template <class T>
//"Stack<T>" é uma classe baseada no "template <class T>".
int Stack<T>::peek() { 
    if (top < 0) { 
        cout << "Stack is Empty" << endl;
        return 0; 
    } else { 
        return a[top];
    } 
} 

//Declarando uso de um template.
template <class T>
//"Stack<T>" é uma <<classe baseada no "template <class T>".
bool Stack<T>::isEmpty() {
    return (top < 0);
}

#endif
```

Well, one part of the code is in: home/matheus/Codes/C++/Aulas and other part is in: home/matheus/Codes/C++/EstruturaDeDados.

I'm trying to compile this with: `g++ -o 21Templates 21Templates.cpp /home/matheus/Codes/C++/EstruturaDeDados/Stack.h`

(Remember that I'm already with the cmd opened in home/matheus/Codes/C++/Aulas, where the 21Templates.cpp are.)

How I do to execute this without receiving the error:

> 21Templates.cpp:2:10: fatal error: Stack.h: archive or directory
>   unexistent
>
> #include "Stack.h"
>
> ```
>        ^~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> compilation terminated.

???

Comment: Please post [mcve] **as text**.  No links.  No pictures.

Comment: Did you tell your compiler to search the folder containing `Stack.h`?

Comment: you could either add the full path to your `#include` or use the -I option

Comment: I'm new at stackoverflow, sorry for using images, but my question alredy was answered.

Comment: if any of those who closed my question can reopen it, i'm new at stackoverflow and so i didn't know i couldn't put the photos with the details instead of the text of the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do `#include "Stack.h"` in your code, you must add the directory where you've placed `Stack.h` using the `-I` option  when compiling:

```
g++ -I /home/matheus/Codes/C++/EstruturaDeDados -o 21Templates 21Templates.cpp
```

Comment: You can help me with other problem with the same code?

Comment: @FUNKYBAT I'm not sure, but there's only one way to find out. Post a new question with the new problem in focus and I'm confident that someone will be able to help out.

Comment: I cannot made other question because i need to wait 3 days for receiving a close im my question.

Comment: @FUNKYBAT Oh, I didn't know it worked that way. Let's hope it gets reopened before that.